# keycloak password hash in token endpoint

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, base64, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

This is what I am doing:
I have a REST API call (login) that takes in a username and password and using that I call the following API:

```
auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

I also pass the client id, username and password in the POST data. and get the right results. No issues.

However, I want to encode the password while sending it in the above REST API call instead of using actual text. In fact, I want the password to be encoded even when someone calls the REST API call that I have implemented.

Please suggest how this could be done. I tried just passing a hashed value, but it did not work.

Thanks in advance.
Anand

Answer (score -1):

Sending a password in the body of a POST request over HTTPS is fine. Hashing the password would give you no much added security: if you're worried about the body of the request being intercepted, intercepting the hash would still give the attacker a way to log in as the user.

If you're worried about security, I would rather try to use the OIDC flow as it should be:

> The authorization server should take special care when enabling [the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant] type and **only allow it when other flows are not viable**.
>
> source: [the OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)

Prefer using the [implicit flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth) if your app is single page app, or, even better, the [authorization code flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth).